# Is there a simple way to remove brackets etc from a selection?

Tags: pycharm, keyboard-shortcuts

In PyCharm I love how smart-keys means I can select an element and then type "[" to surround the selection in brackets (and also parentheses, quotes, braces).

Is there an a way to do the opposite - i.e highlight an element and then remove surrounding brackets etc?

I have already searched Google and Stack Overflow, as well as the PyCharm settings for smartkeys etc for solutions and I see some very old questions about it, but can't find an answer that doesn't boil down to regex or macros...

I'd like to remove surrounding brackets etc from a selection in PyCharm, and I have looked in the product's own settings and searched online.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're out of luck, by default PyCharm doesn't have the feature of removing brackets from around a code block or line segment. You can check the [Smart Keys functionalities in the documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/settings-smart-keys.html) or in the IDE by going to `Settings/Preferences` `>` `Editor` `>` `General` `>` `Smart Keys` but the functionality you want just isn't there.

> but can't find an answer that doesn't boil down to regex or macros...

And you're not going to find one because the IDE doesn't provide the functionality. You would have to implement it using the [live template variables](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/template-variables.html) or as an [external tool](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-third-party-tools.html).

I searched the [JetBrains marketplace](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/search?products=pycharm&search=bracket) for the expectable keywords but aside of [a couple of plugins that come close](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/11322-bracket-selection) there isn't one that does what you want.

Comment: thanks, i feared as much. it seems odd because it's the inverse of something cool they've already done!

Comment: @prosody no problem, a lot of other IDE's have us expecting those kinds of shortcuts but PyCharm puts its emphasis on other kinds of functionalities (in most cases I'd have little use for removing surrounding brackets).

Comment: i'm actually really happy with pycharm, although i'm new and atom is the only other editor i've really used. i was only really using atom for jinja templating plugin and sincei started a pycharm pro trial a few days ago i haven't used it at all.

what am i missing from other ides?

Comment: @prosody I'm from before the time when IDEs existed and everything was programmed using specialized text editors... I've also used many of the most popular IDEs out there, if I had to name a single difference it's that the text editing shortcuts aren't as rich in PyCharm by comparison but it's pretty good at everything else. (I also really like Notepad++, give it a try if you ever need something extra.)

Comment: i use notepad++ for pretty much everything except for coding and have never explored it's advanced features (beyond darkmode and autosave lol) ... what kind of shortcuts are you talking about?

Comment: @prosody I'll give one killer example to keep this short: Say you have 100 tabs... In Notepad++ you get [these convenient options](https://npp-user-manual.org/docs/other-resources/) to move them around. In PyCharm if you want to move tabs you have to install a [3rd party plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/10131-tabmover) there's no way to do it vanilla (I mean the actions aren't part of the IDE - it's not just configuring the keymap). (I've found myself searching for PyCharm plugins that satisfy basic stuff like this more times than I'd care to admit.)